# Exception: The content of element type "hibernate-mapping" must match "

Tags: xml, hibernate, exception, hibernate-mapping

I'm getting the following error:

```
<my correct path>/applicationContext_AuthService.xml]: Invocation of init method failed;     nested exception is org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Unable to read XML
```

Then further down the cause is revealed:

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The content of element type "hibernate-mapping" must match "(meta*,identifier-generator*,typedef*,filter-def*,import*,(class|subclass|joined-subclass|union-subclass)*,resultset*,(query|sql-query)*,filter-def*,fetch-profile*,database-object*)".
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:131)
```

The exception is referencing the file applicationContext_AuthService.xml.  In there I have the following mappings:

```
    <bean id="UserAPPSessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="UserAPP" />
    </property>
    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <!-- value>hib/userapp/ActionImpl.hbm.xml</value -->
            <value>hib/userapp/ActivityCode.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>hib/userapp/Authorization.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>hib/userapp/Contacts.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>hib/userapp/CorrectionRequests.hbm.xml</value>
            <!-- value>hib/userapp/CSRHistory.hbm.xml</value -->
            <value>hib/userapp/Csrusers.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>hib/userapp/Customer.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>hib/userapp/CustomerTypeImpl.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>hib/userapp/DocumentAssociationCrosswalk.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>hib/userapp/DocumentImpl.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>hib/userapp/KeyDB.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>hib/userapp/KeyDBFirst.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>hib/userapp/NotesImpl.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>hib/userapp/Product.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>hib/userapp/RatesImpl.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>hib/userapp/ReminderImpl.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>hib/userapp/YearImpl.hbm.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
```

The second one is hib/userapp/Authorization.hbm.xml.  Here is that file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
    <!-- Generated Aug 17, 2011 3:35:48 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
    <hibernate-mapping>
        <class name="com.eagle.customer.impl.AuthorizationImpl" table="CustomerAuthorization"
    schema="dbo" catalog="UserAPP">
    <cache usage="read-write" />
    <id name="custId" type="string">
        <column name="CustID" length="10" />
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>
    <property name="password" type="string">
        <column name="Password" length="15" />
    </property>
    <property name="custType" type="string">
        <column name="CustType" length="10" />
    </property>
    <property name="authLevel" type="string">
        <column name="AuthLevel" length="2" />
    </property>
    <property name="custStatus" type="string">
        <column name="CustStatus" length="10" />
    </property>
    <property name="vincaptureHbm" type="string">
        <column name="VINCapture" length="1" />
    </property>
    <property name="mileageReportHbm" type="string">
        <column name="MileageReport" length="1" />
    </property>
</class>
```

This is the one that I think it is complaining about.  It is valid xml according to XMLSpy.

Anybody have any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Andrew

Comment: For anyone else having this problem mine was caused by `<filter-def>` tags not being at the last tags in the `<hibernate-mapping>` parent.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the last line, unless that's a copy-paste error:

```
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Can you confirm that it's this file? Try commenting it out and see if the error disappears (or gives a different one).